# How to convert xml_node to data frame in R (with multiple namespaces)?

Tags: r, xml, shiny

I have a huge xml file (>100mb) which I need to convert into a data frame and perform data visualisation. I've tried the following code to retrieve the nodes, children and colnames that I want for my end dataframe:

```
# Sample XML Data
<feed base="https://someurl" xmlns:a="someurl" xmlns:d="someurl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <title type="text">Some Title</title>
  <id>someurl...</id>
  <author><name/></author>
  <link rel="self" title="sometitle" href="somelink"/>
  <entry>
   <id>someurl</id>
   <title type="text" />
   <author><name/></author>
   <link rel="self" title="title" href="someurl">
   <category term="sometype" scheme="someurl">
   <content type="application/xml">
     <a:something>
       <d:RAW_ID m:type="Edm.String">123456</d:RAW_ID>
       <d:EMPLOYEE_ID m:type="Edm.Int">1234</d:EMPLOYEE_ID>
       <d:IN_TIME m:type="Edm.String">2018-10-21 03:45:00.0000000</d:IN_TIME>
       <d:OUT_TIME m:type="Edm.String">2018-10-21 03:46:00.0000000</d:OUT_TIME>
       ...
       ...
       ...
     </a:something>
   </content>
 </entry>
 <entry>
   ....data repeats...
 </entry>
 ...
```

And here is my R Code:

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

# Get xml data
response <- GET("someURL", authenticate("username", "password")

# Read xml
doc <- read_xml(response)

# Get all the relevant nodes
recs <- xml_find_all(x, "//a:something")
child <- xml_children(recs)

recs and child looks like the following respectively:

recs
{xml_nodeset (1234)}
[1] <a:something>\n  <d:RAW_ID m:type="Edm.String">123456</d:RAW_ID>\n  <d:USER_ID m:type="Edm.I ...
[2] <a:something>\n  <d:RAW_ID m:type="Edm.String">234567</d:RAW_ID>\n  <d:USER_ID m:type="Edm.I ...
[3] <a:something>\n  <d:RAW_ID m:type="Edm.String">345678</d:RAW_ID>\n  <d:USER_ID m:type="Edm.I ...
[4] ...
[5] ...

{xml_nodeset (123456)}

 [1] <d:RAW_ID m:type="Edm.String">123456</d:RAW_ID>
 [2] <d:USER_ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1234</d:USER_ID>
 [3] <d:IN_TIME m:type="Edm.String">2018-10-21 03:45:00.0000000</d:IN_TIME>
 [4] <d:OUT_TIME m:type="Edm.String">2018-10-21 03:46:00.0000000</d:OUT_TIME>
 [5] <d:DATE m:type="Edm.String">2018-10-21</d:DATE>
 [6] ...
 [7] ...
 [8] ...
```

However, I'm not sure how I should convert the xml_nodeset into a dataframe. Can someone please tell me how can I obtain a final data frame that looks like this:

```
RAW_ID   USER_ID  IN_TIME                      OUT_TIME          DATE  ...
123456   1234     2018-10-21 03:45:00.0000000  03:46:00.0000000  2018-10-21
234567   2345     2018-10-21 04:46:00.0000000  04:46:00.0000000  2018-10-21
345678   4567     2018-10-21 05:47:00.0000000  04:46:00.0000000  2018-10-21
```

Also, as the xml file is huge, is there a better way for me to speed up the GET request such that it takes a faster time to run my Shiny application? I would need to perform data cleaning and then passing it into ggplot for visualisation. However, it does not make sense to perform the data cleaning every single time the Shiny app is run.

Any tips / suggestions on how I can make this process more efficient?

Comment: (a) We don't have the data just partial nodeset diag output; (b) please read docs as all of the _"find node(s)"_ ƒ have a _rly explicitly named_ `ns` param; (c) `?xml2::xml_ns_strip`; (d) just cache the XML file locally (&, if you're re-d/l a large file that rarely changes, that's terrible internet manners) — there are many e.g. of this on the internet & CRAN has a few  that involve caching content but it's no fancier than saving new things to a central location and testing for presence of them locally before re-downloading. You cld also cache post-processed data to avoid re-processing.

Comment: Hi @hrbrmstr, thanks for your advice! Here are my replies to your points: (a) I have edited my question and added the sample xml data. Hopefully this is a better reproducible example of the problem that I'm facing. Could you provide me with a step by step answer to obtaining my desired data frame? (b) and (c): Okay will read up on the docs (d) How do I cache the post-processed data to avoid re-processing? Could you share an example or url to this? Any further help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: get library(plyr), and can you try:  ldply(xmlToList(xmlParse(recs)), data.frame)